# Injecting values depending on the object to be injected

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following scenario:

```
public class InjectionTest {
    private static class Sub {
        @Inject private final String value = null;
    }
    private static class General {
        @Inject private final Sub sub = null;
    }
    private static class MainOne {
        @Inject private final General general = null;
    }
    private static class MainTwo {
        @Inject private final General general = null;
    }
    public static void main(String... arguments) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override protected void configure() {
                /* DO MAGIC */
            }
        });
        MainOne mainOne = injector.getInstance(MainOne.class);
        MainTwo mainTwo = injector.getInstance(MainTwo.class);
        assertThat(mainOne.general.sub.value, is("one"));
        assertThat(mainTwo.general.sub.value, is("two"));
    }
}
```

I want the `value` accessible from the instance of `MainOne` to be `"one"` and the `value` accessible from the `MainTwo` instance to be `"two"`. I have tried the following:

- Using Guice’s `Named` annotation; unfortunately this requires that I create the `General` instances myself or use a child injectors to create the `Sub` instances.
- Using Guice’s `Scope` mechanism. I couldn’t really get it to work the way I wanted to and got the feeling that it was never intended to do this and in fact even *can not* do this at all.

(Of course the real scenario is more complicated, as always: I have a `GuiceServletContextListener` and a `ServletModule` and I’m trying to reuse a couple of classes/services among all created `Servlet` instances but also need a couple of specialized modules that are requested from the servlets.)

Am I missing anything? Is there a (relatively) easy way to achieve what I want?

Comment: This is called the "robot legs" problem.  Here's Guice's advice: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't inject into final fields (see comments). I suggest that you remove the `final` modifier, or use constructor injection.

It's possible to solve your example by using private modules. But I don't consider this an "easy" solution.

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new PrivateModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(String.class).toInstance("one");
            bind(MainOne.class);

            expose(MainOne.class);
        }
    }, new PrivateModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(String.class).toInstance("two");
            bind(MainTwo.class);

            expose(MainTwo.class);
        }
    });
```

I think you're better off using either `@Named` or creating your own binding annotation.

Also read the wiki page on the "robots leg" problem:
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects

Comment: Actually you [can](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#field-injection) inject into final fields but it's not a good idea.

Comment: It's a bad idea. That why it only works with the `@com.google.inject.Inject` annotation. If you try this with the `@javax.inject.Inject`, Guice 3.0 fails with an `CreationException`.